# Can I share the same WSO2_CARBON database between API Manager and Business Activity Monitor?

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I am installing and configuring a BAM aside an AM, following the documentation [Monitoring Using WSO2 BAM](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Monitoring+Using+WSO2+BAM#MonitoringUsingWSO2BAM-ConfiguringBAM).

The DBMS is MySQL. May I configure the BAM and the AM to use the same WSO2_CARBON database?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can share. And it will work fine.

Sharing the same database with BAM and APIM means you are sharing all the tables used within the carbon server such as registry tables, user-mgt tables, and so forth, since by default the registry, etc is wso2carbondb.

Comment: Thanks Sinthuja, in order to complete the answer do you have reference documentation by WSO2? or any use-case scenario? Thanks!